# Why does this javascript code returns 3 as counter value?

Tags: javascript, closures

So, recently I've been trying to learn javascript and I came accross this code

```
var add = (function () {
  var counter = 0;
  return function () {counter += 1; return counter}
})();

add();
add();
add();
```

by executing this, counter becomes 3. But there are some things that I have too much trouble to understand. such as what is return function statement doing? To me, it seems there's another anonymous function is returned inside a function. but i have no idea how does this code work. And I've been really trying to understand this for hours.

Here is another code:

```
function add() {
  var counter = 0;
  counter += 1;
  return counter;
}

// Call add() 3 times
add();
add();
add();
```

but it returns counter value as 1 (which i understand) so why was the previous code returning 3. I need an in-depth explanation please. I have spent hours learning about closures on w3schools, mdn documentation and youtube tutorials and I think I have understood the closures ( at least some of it). but I can't make sense of this code. So, i really need your help. Thanks.

Comment: in the first example counter is stored in closure, in second example you're creating a new counter variable each time you execute add

Comment: Here are some documentation for  [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first example, you are creating an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE).  The `add` variable is being initialized to the return of the function call.  In this case `add` is equal to `function() { counter += 1; return counter; }`.

The reason that counter is 3 at the end is because within the IIFE you create a local scope with the variable `counter`.  This variable is only accessible inside of that scope. So if you try to access `counter` after calling `add()` it would not exist.

In your second example, every time you call `add()`, you are creating a new variable in the local scope.  So every call starts at `0`.

You can read more about scope here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Differences

If you want the same functionality as the IIFE in your second example, you can simply declare the `counter` variable outside of the function.

```
let counter = 0;
const add = () => ++counter;
add();
add();
add();
```

Alternatively, you can pass in the variable you wish to increment.

```
let counter = 0;
const add = (increment) => ++increment;
counter = add(add(add(counter)));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, man.So I'm beginning to understand this. However, I have one question. could we have achieved the same output in the first code without the return from return function? if so, how? I tried simply removing the return and only leaving function but didn't work. asking because never seen a return used in that way. so if you could explain that, then that'd be very helpful. thanks

Comment: @ZainAbedin Sure, I updated my answer to show how you could do that.  Out of curiosity, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: oh thanks. i just read it. I didn't write the code, I was just reading about closures on w3schools site and came accross this code and really couldn't understand it so asked about it here

Comment: Sure thing.  Basically the outer function is being called immediately and the result is a function that is store in the variable `add`

Comment: oh okay. Thanks a lot for the help man. I was going mental. Now, I understand the working, Thanks you so much, man.

Answer (score 1):

Read more about closure in JavaScript you could in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Emulating_private_methods_with_closures).

> The shared lexical environment is created in the body of an anonymous function, which is executed as soon as it has been defined. The lexical environment contains private variable called `counter`. Private variable couldn't be accessed directly from outside the anonymous function. Instead, they must be accessed by the public function that is returned from the anonymous wrapper.

Comment: oh okay. thanks for the answer. could you explain about return function in line 3 of code 1? because i've never seen it in use and when im trying to google it only tells me about return statement